# Makefile.in and variable substitution

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

In `Makefile.in` I see variable definition where an external variable name is enclosed between two `@` symbols

```
# @configure_input@

package = @PACKAGE_NAME@
```

Where those external variables come from? Also, I couldn't find in GNU manual what does exactly enclosing a variable between two `@` symbols mean? Is it something specific to Makefile.in?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an autoconf thing.

When `./configure` finishes running, it generates and executes a file called `config.status`, which is a shell script that has the final value of the variable substitutions (anything declared with `AC_SUBST`).

Anything that is declared in `AC_CONFIG_FILES` is processed by `config.status`, usually by turning `foo.in` into `foo`.

When automake processes `Makefile.am` into `Makefile.in`, any `AC_SUBST` variable is automatically made available (using a declaration like `FOO = @FOO@`), unless it's suppressed by a call to `AM_SUBST_NOTMAKE`.

Comment: What about `PACKAGE_NAME` in the question? In my `Makefile.am` I used `@datadir@/@package_name@`, and it was substituted to `${datarootdir}/@package_name@`, which is obviously not correct.

Comment: `PACKAGE_NAME` is special - it's set by `AC_INIT` as tiwo mentions below.

Answer (score 5):

(I am not an expert, but) Yes they are specific to Makefile.in, and [`configure`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) replaces them when assembling the `Makefile`, see  [the Autoconf Manual, section 4.8](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Makefile-Substitutions). For example, `@PACKAGE_NAME@` is defined by [AC_INIT](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Initializing-configure).

Comment: Also read [Jack's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11648552) (and give him that checkmark).